# Deserialization of json file

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm having a hard time deserializing a JSON file I'm getting from an API. This is the class structure I have created based on the file:

```
namespace Huskeliste {
 public class RecipeClass {
  public class Rootobject {
    public string q { get; set; }
    public int from { get; set; }
    public int to { get; set; }
    public bool more { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Hit[] hits { get; set; }
  }

  public class Hit {
    public Recipe recipe { get; set; }
    public bool bookmarked { get; set; }
    public bool bought { get; set; }
  }

  public class Recipe {
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string shareAs { get; set; }
    public float yield { get; set; }
    public string[] dietLabels { get; set; }
    public string[] healthLabels { get; set; }
    public string[] cautions { get; set; }
    public string[] ingredientLines { get; set; }
    public Ingredient[] ingredients { get; set; }
    public float calories { get; set; }
    public float totalWeight { get; set; }
    public float totalTime { get; set; }
    public Digest[] digest { get; set; }
  }

  public class Ingredient {
    public string text { get; set; }
    public float weight { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
  }

  public class Digest {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string schemaOrgTag { get; set; }
    public float total { get; set; }
    public bool hasRDI { get; set; }
    public float daily { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public Sub[] sub { get; set; }
  }

  public class Sub {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string schemaOrgTag { get; set; }
    public float total { get; set; }
    public bool hasRDI { get; set; }
    public float daily { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
  }

  }
}

// This is my deserialization code:
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  string json = client.DownloadString(strurl);
  var example = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Class1.Rootobject>(json);
  TextBox1.Text = example.hits[0].recipe.label.ToString();
}
```

The error I get is: The index is outside of the bounds of the array. I have tried changing code to:
`var example = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Class1.hit>(json);`
but this does not work either.

Json file:

{
"q": "fish",
"from": 0,
"to": 1,
"more": true,
"count": 15241,
"hits": [
{
"recipe": {
"uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_672c9e7e3fbc6240477d99152ba8f6b3",
"label": "Burnt-Scallion Fish",
"image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/a96/a967fbe797803dbe8418a668cf304b53.jpg",
"source": "Saveur",
"url": "http://www.saveur.com/article/Recipes/Burnt-Scallion-Fish",
"shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/burnt-scallion-fish-672c9e7e3fbc6240477d99152ba8f6b3/fish",
"yield": 6.0,
"dietLabels": [
"Low-Carb"
],
"healthLabels": [
"Sugar-Conscious",
"Peanut-Free",
"Tree-Nut-Free",
"Alcohol-Free",
"Immuno-Supportive"
],
"cautions": [],
"ingredientLines": [
"2 bunches scallions",
"8 tbsp. butter",
"2 8-oz. fish filets"
],
"ingredients": [
{
"text": "2 bunches scallions",
"weight": 226.0,
"image": "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/b89/b89986ed6aa466285bdd99bac34b3c46.jpg"
},
{
"text": "8 tbsp. butter",
"weight": 113.6,
"image": null
},
{
"text": "2 8-oz. fish filets",
"weight": 453.59237,
"image": "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/717/717cb400eb49626bb7c95cd29292cef4.jpg"
}
],
"calories": 1322.2806752000001,
"totalWeight": 793.19237,
"totalTime": 0.0,
"totalNutrients": {
"ENERC_KCAL": {
"label": "Energy",
"quantity": 1322.2806752000001,
"unit": "kcal"
},
"FAT": {
"label": "Fat",
"quantity": 100.28143028999999,
"unit": "g"
},
"FASAT": {
"label": "Saturated",
"quantity": 61.0798833645,
"unit": "g"
},
"FATRN": {
"label": "Trans",
"quantity": 3.7238079999999996,
"unit": "g"
},
"FAMS": {
"label": "Monounsaturated",
"quantity": 26.1997660026,
"unit": "g"
},
"FAPU": {
"label": "Polyunsaturated",
"quantity": 5.2706283031000005,
"unit": "g"
},
"CHOCDF": {
"label": "Carbs",
"quantity": 16.65656,
"unit": "g"
},
"FIBTG": {
"label": "Fiber",
"quantity": 5.876000000000001,
"unit": "g"
},
"SUGAR": {
"label": "Sugars",
"quantity": 5.33396,
"unit": "g"
},
"PROCNT": {
"label": "Protein",
"quantity": 96.182747896,
"unit": "g"
},
"CHOLE": {
"label": "Cholesterol",
"quantity": 471.03618500000005,
"unit": "mg"
},
"NA": {
"label": "Sodium",
"quantity": 284.5240324,
"unit": "mg"
},
"CA": {
"label": "Calcium",
"quantity": 235.34323700000004,
"unit": "mg"
},
"MG": {
"label": "Magnesium",
"quantity": 169.94193990000002,
"unit": "mg"
},
"K": {
"label": "Potassium",
"quantity": 2020.8729574000004,
"unit": "mg"
},
"FE": {
"label": "Iron",
"quantity": 5.9076372720000006,
"unit": "mg"
},
"ZN": {
"label": "Zinc",
"quantity": 2.4804948210000006,
"unit": "mg"
},
"P": {
"label": "Phosphorus",
"quantity": 881.9910290000001,
"unit": "mg"
},
"VITA_RAE": {
"label": "Vitamin A",
"quantity": 890.0239999999999,
"unit": "µg"
},
"VITC": {
"label": "Vitamin C",
"quantity": 42.48800000000001,
"unit": "mg"
},
"THIA": {
"label": "Thiamin (B1)",
"quantity": 0.3159528717000001,
"unit": "mg"
},
"RIBF": {
"label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
"quantity": 0.5051871931,
"unit": "mg"
},
"NIA": {
"label": "Niacin (B3)",
"quantity": 18.9379222011,
"unit": "mg"
},
"VITB6A": {
"label": "Vitamin B6",
"quantity": 0.8760876394000001,
"unit": "mg"
},
"FOLDFE": {
"label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
"quantity": 256.9101688,
"unit": "µg"
},
"FOLFD": {
"label": "Folate (food)",
"quantity": 256.9101688,
"unit": "µg"
},
"FOLAC": {
"label": "Folic acid",
"quantity": 0.0,
"unit": "µg"
},
"VITB12": {
"label": "Vitamin B12",
"quantity": 7.359879446000002,
"unit": "µg"
},
"VITD": {
"label": "Vitamin D",
"quantity": 15.76536347,
"unit": "µg"
},
"TOCPHA": {
"label": "Vitamin E",
"quantity": 5.69288948,
"unit": "mg"
},
"VITK1": {
"label": "Vitamin K",
"quantity": 482.12229318000004,
"unit": "µg"
},
"WATER": {
"label": "Water",
"quantity": 577.5605624960001,
"unit": "g"
}
},
"totalDaily": {
"ENERC_KCAL": {
"label": "Energy",
"quantity": 66.11403376000001,
"unit": "%"
},
"FAT": {
"label": "Fat",
"quantity": 154.27912352307692,
"unit": "%"
},
"FASAT": {
"label": "Saturated",
"quantity": 305.39941682250003,
"unit": "%"
},
"CHOCDF": {
"label": "Carbs",
"quantity": 5.552186666666667,
"unit": "%"
},
"FIBTG": {
"label": "Fiber",
"quantity": 23.504000000000005,
"unit": "%"
},
"PROCNT": {
"label": "Protein",
"quantity": 192.365495792,
"unit": "%"
},
"CHOLE": {
"label": "Cholesterol",
"quantity": 157.01206166666668,
"unit": "%"
},
"NA": {
"label": "Sodium",
"quantity": 11.855168016666667,
"unit": "%"
},
"CA": {
"label": "Calcium",
"quantity": 23.534323700000005,
"unit": "%"
},
"MG": {
"label": "Magnesium",
"quantity": 40.46236664285715,
"unit": "%"
},
"K": {
"label": "Potassium",
"quantity": 42.99729696595745,
"unit": "%"
},
"FE": {
"label": "Iron",
"quantity": 32.82020706666667,
"unit": "%"
},
"ZN": {
"label": "Zinc",
"quantity": 22.549952918181823,
"unit": "%"
},
"P": {
"label": "Phosphorus",
"quantity": 125.99871842857145,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITA_RAE": {
"label": "Vitamin A",
"quantity": 98.89155555555556,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITC": {
"label": "Vitamin C",
"quantity": 47.2088888888889,
"unit": "%"
},
"THIA": {
"label": "Thiamin (B1)",
"quantity": 26.329405975000007,
"unit": "%"
},
"RIBF": {
"label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
"quantity": 38.860553315384614,
"unit": "%"
},
"NIA": {
"label": "Niacin (B3)",
"quantity": 118.362013756875,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITB6A": {
"label": "Vitamin B6",
"quantity": 67.39135687692308,
"unit": "%"
},
"FOLDFE": {
"label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
"quantity": 64.2275422,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITB12": {
"label": "Vitamin B12",
"quantity": 306.66164358333344,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITD": {
"label": "Vitamin D",
"quantity": 105.10242313333333,
"unit": "%"
},
"TOCPHA": {
"label": "Vitamin E",
"quantity": 37.952596533333335,
"unit": "%"
},
"VITK1": {
"label": "Vitamin K",
"quantity": 401.76857765000005,
"unit": "%"
}
},
"digest": [
{
"label": "Fat",
"tag": "FAT",
"schemaOrgTag": "fatContent",
"total": 100.28143028999999,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 154.27912352307692,
"unit": "g",
"sub": [
{
"label": "Saturated",
"tag": "FASAT",
"schemaOrgTag": "saturatedFatContent",
"total": 61.0798833645,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 305.39941682250003,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Trans",
"tag": "FATRN",
"schemaOrgTag": "transFatContent",
"total": 3.7238079999999996,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Monounsaturated",
"tag": "FAMS",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 26.1997660026,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Polyunsaturated",
"tag": "FAPU",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 5.2706283031000005,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
}
]
},
{
"label": "Carbs",
"tag": "CHOCDF",
"schemaOrgTag": "carbohydrateContent",
"total": 16.65656,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 5.552186666666667,
"unit": "g",
"sub": [
{
"label": "Carbs (net)",
"tag": "CHOCDF.net",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 10.780559999999998,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Fiber",
"tag": "FIBTG",
"schemaOrgTag": "fiberContent",
"total": 5.876000000000001,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 23.504000000000005,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Sugars",
"tag": "SUGAR",
"schemaOrgTag": "sugarContent",
"total": 5.33396,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Sugars, added",
"tag": "SUGAR.added",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.0,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
}
]
},
{
"label": "Protein",
"tag": "PROCNT",
"schemaOrgTag": "proteinContent",
"total": 96.182747896,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 192.365495792,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Cholesterol",
"tag": "CHOLE",
"schemaOrgTag": "cholesterolContent",
"total": 471.03618500000005,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 157.01206166666668,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Sodium",
"tag": "NA",
"schemaOrgTag": "sodiumContent",
"total": 284.5240324,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 11.855168016666667,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Calcium",
"tag": "CA",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 235.34323700000004,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 23.534323700000005,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Magnesium",
"tag": "MG",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 169.94193990000002,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 40.46236664285715,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Potassium",
"tag": "K",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 2020.8729574000004,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 42.99729696595745,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Iron",
"tag": "FE",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 5.9076372720000006,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 32.82020706666667,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Zinc",
"tag": "ZN",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 2.4804948210000006,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 22.549952918181823,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Phosphorus",
"tag": "P",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 881.9910290000001,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 125.99871842857145,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin A",
"tag": "VITA_RAE",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 890.0239999999999,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 98.89155555555556,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin C",
"tag": "VITC",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 42.48800000000001,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 47.2088888888889,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Thiamin (B1)",
"tag": "THIA",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.3159528717000001,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 26.329405975000007,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
"tag": "RIBF",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.5051871931,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 38.860553315384614,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Niacin (B3)",
"tag": "NIA",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 18.9379222011,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 118.362013756875,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin B6",
"tag": "VITB6A",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.8760876394000001,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 67.39135687692308,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Folate equivalent (total)",
"tag": "FOLDFE",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 256.9101688,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 64.2275422,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Folate (food)",
"tag": "FOLFD",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 256.9101688,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Folic acid",
"tag": "FOLAC",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.0,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin B12",
"tag": "VITB12",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 7.359879446000002,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 306.66164358333344,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin D",
"tag": "VITD",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 15.76536347,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 105.10242313333333,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin E",
"tag": "TOCPHA",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 5.69288948,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 37.952596533333335,
"unit": "mg"
},
{
"label": "Vitamin K",
"tag": "VITK1",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 482.12229318000004,
"hasRDI": true,
"daily": 401.76857765000005,
"unit": "µg"
},
{
"label": "Sugar alcohols",
"tag": "Sugar.alcohol",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 0.0,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
},
{
"label": "Water",
"tag": "WATER",
"schemaOrgTag": null,
"total": 577.5605624960001,
"hasRDI": false,
"daily": 0.0,
"unit": "g"
}
]
},
"bookmarked": false,
"bought": false
}
]
}

Comment: I suggest tagging a language/environment. Looks like C#?

Comment: Example of the JSON also would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your Json to C# classes with this site and then check if you got the same class structure (https://json2csharp.com)
And maybe use Newtonsoft, it works perfectly every time.

I created a Console App and tested your Json file. It worked, so idk what is going wrong in your program. In your example you refer to "Class1.Rootobject", I hope you used the correct reference in your program?

Maybe debug it and check if the json is not empty there.

```
 string jsonPath = @"C:\temp\Stackoverflow1.txt";
 string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
 var example = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RecipeClass.Rootobject>(json);
 string text = example.hits[0].recipe.label.ToString();
```